# Do we have to retain object returned by a method in non-ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, release, retain

Consider a situation implemented in Manual Retain Release, where I have a variable pointing to an object returned by a method.

```
{
    ...
    NSString *str = [self myNewString];
    ...
}

- (NSString *)myNewString
{
    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-String", 1];
    return myString;
}
```

Here do we have to retain the object returned by `myNewString` so that it wont be released while we are using it?

Please help I am new to Objective-C. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're just learning Objective-C, learn ARC instead. Manual reference counting is just another thing you can get wrong, and it buys you absolutely nothing.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the advice. But I am keen on understanding what actually happens under the hood. So I have begun to learn the Manual Reference Counting.

Comment: It's admirable that you want to develop an in depth understanding of Objectivr-C, but I'll urge you again to learn Modern Objective-C/ARC. It emphasizes the relationships between objects, rather than the mechanical and automate-able reference counting.

Comment: I wanted to learn manual reference counting too when I started until I wrote my first ARC program, and I realized that I'd wasted all the time I'd spent learning reference counting. All I can do is advise you not to make the same mistake.

Comment: @godel9: Understanding MRC is very useful. In ARC the compiler simply automates the MRC memory management rules. That means it has the same issues that are encountered in MRC, e.g. retain cycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two aspects to this answer:

1. First, you want to conform to the method naming rule, that dictates that any method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” should have a +1 retain count (i.e. ownership is transferred), otherwise it should be an `autorelease` object (or, more accurately, any object whose ownership is not transferred, and if the caller wants to claim ownership, it would have to manually `retain` it).

   By the way, ARC uses these method name prefixes to determine the object memory semantics automatically, but in manual retain and release (MRR) code, the burden rests with the programmer to ensure that the memory management of the method conforms to the semantics implied by the method's name. Following this method naming rule will become important if you ever integrate this MRR code with ARC code at some future date. There are code hints you can use if you have legacy code that violates this method naming convention, but it's really just better to make sure your code's memory semantics are in conformance with this method naming rule.

   Regardless, this method naming rule is included in the [Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1) outlined in the *Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide.*

   So, in manual retain and release, you have one of two choices. If the method starts with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”, then it should transfer ownership by returning a +1 `retainCount` object, e.g.:

   ```
   - (NSString *)newSomeString
   {
       return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d-String", 1];
   }
   ```

   otherwise, it should not transfer ownership (e.g. return an `autorelease` object), such as:

   ```
   - (NSString *)someString
   {
       return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-String", 1];
   }
   ```
2. So, if the caller wanted to make sure the object was retained, it could either just call the method that returned the +1 object:

   ```
   NSString *string = [self newSomeString];
   ```

   or, call the version that returns an `autorelease` object, but then explicitly `retain` it:

   ```
   NSString *string = [[self someString] retain];
   ```

In practice, the latter convention, the `someString` example, is more common (use method that returns `autorelease` object, i.e. where the method name does *not* start with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”; and then if the caller needs to `retain` it, it should just explicitly do so). The `new`, `copy`, and `mutableCopy` methods all are generally used within respective, very specific contexts, which don't apply here.

By the way, if you run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu), it does a remarkably good job warning you if your MRR code has issues with over retaining objects or failing to retain them.

But bottom line, carefully follow the [basic memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1), including the convention for naming methods, and then if you need it retained, explicitly `retain` your `autorelease` object or call a method that returns  a +1 `retainCount` object.

Comment: This makes me more clear. In case I've created the string using alloc i need not retain it on receiving. But if I've created it using any of the class method like stringWithFormat, I will have to retain it to ensure it lives till i require it. Have I got it right @Rob?

Comment: @user3008132 Yep, that is basically right. And also make sure that the name of your method matches the type of object being returned (e.g. start method name with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” if it's return +1 object created with `alloc`/`init`; don't start the method with one of those four strings if you're returning an `autorelease` object, e.g. an object created with `stringWithFormat`). In this case, I'd advise a method called `someString` (or whatever) that returned an object created with `stringWithFormat`, and have the caller manually `retain` it.

Comment: "any method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” should have a +1 retain count" You forgot `retain`

Comment: "otherwise, it should return an autoreleased object" It doesn't have to be autoreleased. It just have to not have +1 retain semantics.

Comment: @newacct Yes, the MRR `retain` method increases retain count. But we're talking about method name prefixes, and `retain` is _not_ a method name prefix that should transfer ownership (like the `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, and `mutableCopy` prefixes should). If you write MRR method called, for example, `retainSomeObject`, that attempts to transfer ownership, (a) the static analyzer will warn you of that error; and (b) if you integrate that MRR code with ARC code, you'll leak (unless you use `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` qualifier to inform compiler that you're violating method naming rules).

Comment: @newacct Re `autorelease`, you're right that this is not the only pattern that does not transfer ownership (using the "ownership" concept outlined in the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1)). The `autorelease` object is the one relevant for this particular question, but I've tried to clarify my answer, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing just the address of location where NSString object is stored. So, definitely object would be retained by compiler. But you don't have to worry. ARC will take care of releasing memory once the reference count is 0. 
Here you go [Learn more about ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question. My situation in when I am using Manual Reference Counting and not ARC. Thank You.

Comment: Yeah.. in that case you don't need to retain it, as there will not be any ARC to clear it off. But you have to release it as soon as it is unnecessary. Please go through the link i've provided. helped me to understand minute details which i didn't knew on top level of ARC

Comment: Hey.. I didn't understand why you accepted other answer.. As you said you were looking for Manual Reference Counting.. Other answer talks about ARC.. Please verify it again & let me know if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Basically any method that returns a new object besides `new`/`alloc`+`init` Returns it without ownership, meaning that you can count on it sticking around until the enclosing autoreleasepool drains, but no telling after that. If you want to keep it around longer, you must retain it.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is invalid for Manual Reference Counting. As it is clearly mentioned in question, person is talking about Manual Reference Counting.

Comment: @achievelimitless If you think this answer is not useful or clearly wrong, you should downvote it instead of flagging it as "not an answer".

Comment: Sorry @jack.. don't have enough reputation to down vote it :(

Comment: @achievelimitless: "not an answer" flags are not a substitute for downvotes. They have different purposes - that's precisely why they exist separately.

Comment: @achievelimitless This answer does apply to MRC, and not ARC. What exactly do you think is incorrect about it? `stringWithFormat` returns an `autorelease`d string. Everything is enclosed in an autoreleasepool in the run loop, and the object will stick around until that pool is drained, after the calling method returns.

Comment: you are forgetting `copy` and `mutableCopy`